# Attempt to define a momentum space wavefunction for a superposition of of 1-particle states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, field-theory, many-body

Consider an arbitrary state in the Fock space constructed by superposing 1-particle states: $$|\psi\rangle=\mathbb{1}|\psi\rangle=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_p}|p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle$$ where I used the completeness relation for 1-particle states. Let me call $\langle p|\psi\rangle\equiv\psi(p)$. Therefore, $$|\psi\rangle=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\psi(p)|p\rangle$$ I'm interested in calculating the object $\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle$. Since, $\langle 0|\phi(x)|p\rangle=e^{ip\cdot x}$, I get, $$\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\psi(p)\langle 0|\phi(x)|p\rangle=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\psi(p)e^{ip\cdot x}$$

$\bullet$ How to invert this expression to express $\psi(p)$ (in terms of an integral over the LHS expression)?

$\bullet$ Can $\psi(p)$ be regarded as the momentum space wavefunction corresponding to the state $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: 1. In general, you can't "invert" integrals. 2. What is your requirement for something being able to be regarded as "the momentum space wavefunction", and why can you not check those properties yourself?

Comment: @ACuriousMind- 2. $\psi(p)$ should be square integrable with Born interpretation. If $\psi(p)$ is not invertible how can I check that? Moreover, in the context of non-relativistic quantum mechanics, and with $\mathbb{1}=\int dp |p\rangle\langle p|$, $\psi(p)=\langle p|\psi\rangle$ is called momentum space wavefunction. So I wonder whether this analogy works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle=\int d^3\textbf{p}\ f(p)\ e^{ip\cdot x}\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
f(p)\equiv \frac{1}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\psi(p)
$$

Multiply both sides of $(1)$ with $\mathrm e^{i\vec q\cdot\vec x}$, and integrate over $\mathrm d\vec x$:
$$
\int\mathrm d\vec x\ \mathrm e^{i\vec q\cdot \vec x}\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle=\int d^3\textbf{p}\ f(p)\ \mathrm e^{iE_pt}\int\mathrm d\vec x\ e^{i(\vec q-\vec p)\vec x}
$$

The integral of the exponential generates a delta function, and so
$$
\int\mathrm dx\ \mathrm e^{-i\vec q\cdot\vec x}\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle=(2\pi)^3\int d^3\textbf{p}\ f(p)\mathrm e^{iE_pt}\delta(\vec q-\vec p)
$$
so that
$$
\int\mathrm dx\ \mathrm e^{-i\vec q\cdot\vec x}\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle=(2\pi)^3 f(q)\mathrm e^{iE_qt}
$$

This means that
$$
\psi(p)=2E_p\int\mathrm dx\ \mathrm e^{ip x}\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle
$$

Your second question is meaningless unless you define what you mean by "momentum space wavefunction". You can for example define it by the expression above, in which case the answer is trivially yes: that expression is the momentum space wavefunction, by definition.

Comment: In the comment above addressed at ACuriousMind I defined what I understand by a wavefunction i.e., a function which is square integrable and obeys Born interpretation of probability.

Comment: @SRS the square integrability depends on the details of $|\psi\rangle$. For example, for a one-particle state $\psi(p)$ is **not** square integrable, but for wave packets in general it is square integrable. As for your second point, it is far from clear what the Born interpretation means in QFT. The question is still meaningless unless you properly define what you mean by Born interpretation of probability.

Comment: Using $\langle \psi|\psi\rangle=1$, I could derive $\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\psi^*(p)\psi(p)=1$.

Comment: @SRS sure. $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$ is equivalent to square integrability of $\psi(p)$. The issue is that many kets do not satisfy $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$. For example, a one-particle state has $\langle p|p\rangle=\delta(0)=\infty$, and therefore $\psi(p)$ is not square integrable!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform "Multiply both sides of (1) with $e^{i\vec{q}\cdot \vec{x}}$, and integrate over $\mathrm{d}\vec{x}.$" I assume this was an accident? (I am sorry you must get that a lot.)

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs [sometimes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228401/why-is-the-fourier-transform-more-useful-than-the-hartley-transform-in-physics#comment497716_228408), but not nearly as much as I would like ;-)